# nginx proxy_no_cache doesn't work

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up a caching reverse proxy with 2 conditions; if either is met, it shouldn't be storing the file from origin:

- partial-content request

  request with query string

As configured below, I got nginx to NOT store partial-content requests.
However, it is still storing requests with query string. What am I missing here?

`curl -r 1000-2000 http://edge.com/data/abcdef.dat` [OK. No file stored.]
`wget http://edge.com/data/abcdef.dat?query=string` [Not OK. abcdef.dat stored on edge.]

```
location /data/ {
    set $originuri /origin$uri$is_args$args;
    errorpage 404 = $originuri;
}

location /origin/ {
    proxy_pass http://origin.com:1111;
    proxy_store /mnt1/edge/store;
    proxy_temp_path /mnt1/edge/tmp;
    proxy_set_header If-Range $http_if_range;
    proxy_set_header Range $http_range;
    proxy_no_cache $http_range $http_if_range $is_args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your configuration right, when you pass the request to the origin location for proxying, you're building a URI string which doesn't include a GET query string (i.e. you're flattening the `$args`). If that's what's happening, it would explain why the origin location isn't seeing `$is_args` as true.

This is a hunch on my part - I'd want to look at the request logs to see if it's correct.